# How can i disable Cider (WPF Gui Editor) within VS2008?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml, ide

when developing wpf applications i never use the graphical editor ( aka cider). only the xaml editor. as "cider" needs quite some resources when loaded i wonder if there is a way to completely disable it. This may speed up loading xaml files. 
i heard that this is possible, but as google does not return what i`m looking for, i want to ask the SO community.
any ideas?

regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's quite simple!

At the Tools menu, chose Options, and chose "Text Editor" at the left pane. Expand it, and chose "XAML" sub node. Expand the "XAML" sub node, and check the check box of "Always open documents in full XAML view".

Let me know if it doesn't work for you. :)

Comment: Nice idea, but as in the case of WF it does not actually disable the WF integration, and hence makes VS as slow as a snail..

Comment: To be fair, I think the topic of the question is disabling WPF Designer, not WF. I don't know how to disable WF designer integration. You should create a new question about disabling WF integration. :)

Answer (score 3):

For even better performance, map the .xaml extension to the XML Editor in Tools/Options/Text Editor/File Extension. Your .xaml files will then open much faster. You will lose intellisense, but this is a great option if you can live without it.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

See [this blog post](http://www.dolittle.com/blogs/einar/archive/2008/04/24/quot-disable-quot-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) for specific instructions.  Just turn on "Always open documents in full XAML view."

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the steps suggested above but be ready to get VS crashes after you will install Silverlight 2.0 Tools for Visual Studio or sometimes Expression Blend. If you will start experiencing crashes just try switching back to default settings.