# How can I disable Cider (WPF Gui Editor) within VS2010?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, ide

When opening a XAML file in VS2010 Professional, the studio becomes unresponsive for 5-7 seconds and many local controls are marked with error bars, since they do not support design time usage. This also happens after a debugged application is terminated.

I've got a i5 CPU, 16GB RAM and an SSD, so I don't think my H/W specs are at fault.

I'm already opening documents in full XAML view (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/649551/4918)) and I've closed all clutterboxes (Toolbar, Document Outline, Data Source) to no avail.

Currently I'm using the XML editor for my sanity, but of course this also means no IntelliSense at all.

Is there a way to completely disable the WPF Designer in Visual Studio 2010 without loosing XAML IntelliSense capabilities?

Comment: I've had the same thing happen to me with one of the pages I'm working on currently.  Most of the issue seems to stem from resources in user controls not being resolved correctly for me.  Sadly, the only thing I was able to do is resort to editing that view in Blend (or wait the 10-15 seconds for it to tell me there's a problem).

Comment: Are these controls which give errors are yours? To add designtime functionality is not difficult, it's simple if statement. And any professionally designed third party should not give you errors, contact your vendor instead.

Comment: @Akash: they are my own controls and they have currently no code-behind at all. I do not understand why I should invest resources in designtime support when I do not (want to) use a designer.

Comment: It's not much of time, that time invested will save you a lot while editing. Exception thrown will always slow down .Net environment. Mostly you will need to write two if conditions, one in constrictor or in Loaded event handler, and other in OnApplyTemplate. All you need to do is check DesignerProperties.GetInDesignMode and return from current method.

Comment: @Akash: I've added `if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) return;` into all my constructors and recompiled. It didn't make a dent into the abysmal startup time of cider.

Comment: It also needs to go inside OnApplyTemplate and probably Loaded event handler as well.

Comment: @Akash: you could earn a few points if you would type up a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to use a lightweight XML editor that preserves IntelliSense inside Visual Studio. However I suggest you to try [kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/).

From the website:

> Kaxaml is designed to be "notepad for XAML." It's supposed to be simple and lightweight and make it easy to just try something out. It also has some basic support for intellisense and some fun plugins (including one for snippets, one for cleaning up your XAML and for rendering your XAML to an image).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with WPF XAML. The only way I found so far is to use XML editor. Yes, you will not have IntelliSense anymore but there is no better way here. Using external editors like `Kaxaml` helps only for primitive XAML files which do not use anything from other XAMLs (Kaxaml doesn't support `projects` or at least didn't supported them, so it is not useful for real projects). You can also try using `Expression Blend` for editing XAML files but it is also not that good alternative.

Comment: seems to be the sad truth. unless someone else crops up soon with a better suggestion, I'll stay with the XML editor and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) 
   return;
```

to Constructor, OnApplyTemplate and Loaded event handler, that will ignore all design time processing and make the controls load faster.