# Visual Studio 2010 - WPF disable design view for individual control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, visual-studio-designer

Is there a way to disable the design view of an individual UserControl - without disabling the design view for other controls?

Certain controls of mine do not support design view, and in these cases I would prefer them to just load up the xaml editor.

Is there something I can place in the code to disable the design view?

Answer (score 2):

This question intrigued me. I never use the VS designer anyway. For visual tools I prefer Blend. I only use VS for editing the XAML directly (or code).

If you want to go straight to the XAML editor instead of the designer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649551/how-can-i-disable-cider-wpf-gui-editor-within-vs2008)'s an option. I don't know of any way to disable the designer only for certain views. I suspect that it is not possible unless you write a VS extension.